# How to defined nested object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript, I am trying to create the following but not able run it , Please help me with the error in the syntax of the nested objects in this small code snippet:

```
var Employee = {

    name: "Rohit Sachdeva",                           // Defining the Object with the details
    storeName : "Van Heusen",
    age : 29,
    salary : 30000

    address: {

    "address1": {


      cityName : "Bengaluru",
      state : "Karnataka",
      pinCode: 560078 
               }

}


};
```

Comment: You are missing a comma after the value for `salary`

Comment: You can just use any editor with syntax checking, or even http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html That pagewill tell you `address` is an invalid token, which will tell you that the error is just before it. As others have mentioned, there's no comma after salary.

Comment: @thelostspore thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a comma after salary `salary: 30000,`

```
var Employee = {
  name: "Rohit Sachdeva",                  
  storeName : "Van Heusen",
  age : 29,
  salary : 30000,
  address: {
    "address1": {
      cityName : "Bengaluru",
      state : "Karnataka",
      pinCode: 560078 
     }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: I am trying to write this code in brackets, and It doesnt compile, it say unexpected '(space)'. pincode : 560078, could you please help